# How to use node data in content type as hierarchical select

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type having the following fields

Project Type (Node Reference - Select List)
Project Name (textfield)
Manager (user reference - manager role) - Select List
Employee (user reference - employee role) - Checkboxes

Created two nodes as following

node-1(see Image)

**Project Name** - Project-1

**Manager Name** - Manager-1

**Employee**   -  Emp-2, Emp-3

node-2

**Project Name** - Project-2

**Manager Name** - Manager-3

**Employee**    - Emp-1

[image]

I need to use these fields data in another content type like follows

All Project names to be listed in select list(like node reference). If I choose Project-1 , the relative Manager Name (Manager-1) and Employees(Emp-2, Emp-3) should be loaded automatically(like hierarchical/chain select).

Is there contributed module available for this or I need to create a custom module for this?

Comment: Do you need this in a node form or for filtering on the frontend?

Comment: I need this is in node form (while create content)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need [Reference field option limit](https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit), or module with similar functionality:

> This module allows reference fields of several types to have their widgets' available options limited by the values of other fields in the current entity.
>
> This is best illustrated by examples:
>
> *(...)*
>
> **Example 2: sports and teams**
>
> Suppose you want news stories to be marked as being about a sport and a particular team for that sport, perhaps using taxonomy terms for both. To make editing easier, you would probably like want the 'team' dropdown to be limited to just teams for the current news story's sport.
>
> To achieve this with this module, add the 'sport' field to both news story nodes and team taxonomy terms. Hence the team 'Chudley Cannons' would have as its sport taxonomy term 'Quidditch'. (This probably entails taxonomy term reference fields on terms themselves... which was bound to happen with FieldAPI sooner or later.)
>
> Thus, when editing a news story node, selecting 'Quidditch' as the sport will cause the team reference field widget to update to show only teams which also have 'Quidditch' as their sport.

If this module is not *exactly* what you want, it can be a good start for coding own functionality. At least it solves all AJAX interactions for you, so only part you might need to alter is the actual selection.